# How to receive blob responses using Angular's 2+ @angular/http module?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to provide a pdf download from within an angular 2 app...

this code works:

```
    var reportPost = 'variable=lsdkjf';

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost/a2/pdf.php", true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
            saveAs(blob, "Report.pdf");
        }
    }

    xhr.send(reportPost);
```

but i would have liked to use angular 2's built-in Http client.

a little research:

- angular docs unwritten at time of posting:
  https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/ResponseTypes-enum.html
- not sure if this applies, but the rxjs responseType parameter seems
  to include only text and json:
  https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM/blob/master/doc/operators/ajax.md

and some test code:

```
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    this.http.post('http://localhost/a2/pdf.php', reportPost,  {
        headers: headers
        })
        .retry(3)
        // .map( (res:any) => res.blob() ) // errors out
        .subscribe(
          (dataReceived:any) => {
            var blob = new Blob([dataReceived._body], {type: 'application/pdf'});
            saveAs(blob, "Report.pdf");
          },
          (err:any) => this.logError(err),
          () => console.log('Complete')
        );
```

ps. the saveAs function comes from here: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Comment: Seems like the blob()-method isn't implemented yet. See https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/http/static_response.ts#L89. An issue tracking the implementation status can be found here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2803

Comment: How in the world did you get "saveAs" to work? I've installed the module, installed the typings, and still get "no such function: saveAs" when I run it.. sooooo annoying... how do you include it in the typescript code? (i use webpack, still haven't figured it out)

Comment: i've just been ignoring the error from the TS compiler. it still compiles... sloppy huh?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

With the release of Angular2 final we can define for example a service:

```
@Injectable()
export class AngularService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    download(model: MyModel) { //get file from service
        this.http.post("http://localhost/a2/pdf.php", JSON.stringify(model), {
            method: RequestMethod.Post,
            responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob,
            headers: new Headers({'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
        }).subscribe(
            response => { // download file
                var blob = new Blob([response.blob()], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                var filename = 'file.pdf';
                saveAs(blob, filename);
            },
            error => {
                console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

This service will get the file and then serve it to a user.

Example for zip file: [How to use JAX-RS and Angular 2+ to download a zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39690426/how-to-use-jax-rs-and-angular2-to-download-a-zip-file/39690427#39690427)

Comment: thanks ! i missed the responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob.

Comment: can someone mark this as the correct answer please, I've been looking for this in ages.

Comment: import {ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';

Comment: I had to use http.get(url, <any>{responseType: "application/octet-stream"}), because http.get did not recognize responseType of type ResponseContentType, and requires string. And you can't set other string than "json" so I had to fool TS compiler.

Comment: I get this error `[ts] Property 'blob' does not exist on type 'Blob'.` anyone knows why?

Answer (score 17):

With `@4.3, @5` and [HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/guide/http), I ended up doing:

```
this.http.post(`${environment.server}/my/download`,
                data, 
                {responseType: 'blob', observe: 'response'})
              .map( res => ({content: res.body, 
                             fileName: res.headers.get('content-filename')}));
```

Answer (score 2):

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45666313/4420532

```
return this._http.get('/api/images/' + _id, {responseType: 'blob'}).map(blob => {
  var urlCreator = window.URL;
  return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob));
})
```