# How to use JAX-RS and Angular 2+ to download a zip file

Tags: angular, jakarta-ee, download, jax-rs

How to download a zip file exposed by a JAX-RS resource and serve it to the user with Angular2 final?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given a JAX-RS resource as:

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("/myresource")
public class MyResource {

    @Inject
    MyFacade myFacade;

    @POST
    @Path("/download")
    @Produces({"application/zip"})
    public Response download(@NotNull Request req) {
        byte[] zipFileContent = myFacade.download(req);
        return Response
            .ok(zipFileContent)
            .type("application/zip")
            .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename = \"project.zip\"")
            .build();
    }
}
```

In order to consume and serve the file to an end user using a Angular2 application, we can use a service as:

```
...//other import statements
import fileSaver = require("file-saver");

@Injectable()
export class AngularService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    download(model: MyModel) {
        this.http.post(BASE_URL + "myresource/download", JSON.stringify(model), {
            method: RequestMethod.Post,
            responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob,
            headers: new Headers({'Content-type': 'application/json'})
        }).subscribe(
            (response) => {
                var blob = new Blob([response.blob()], {type: 'application/zip'});
                var filename = 'file.zip';
                fileSaver.saveAs(blob, filename);
        }
    );
}
```

For this to work the `fileSaver` should be imported in `package.json` as:

```
"dependencies": {
    // all angular2 dependencies... 
    "file-saver": "1.3.2"
 },
```

And that service can be now injected on any component that requires access to the `download` method