# Angular 2 : display binary image served with express js

Tags: angular, express

I have an image in the server and I want to send it to the client : 
here is my server side code :

```
var options = {
    root: './Images/',
    dotfiles: 'deny',
    headers: {
        'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
        'x-sent': true
    }
};
var fileName = "a.png";
BillModel.getBillsModel((err, config_model) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error from database " + err)
        //res.json({ code: 0, error: err, response: null })
    } else {
        res.sendFile(fileName, options, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log('Sent:', fileName);
            }
        });
   }
```

and here my code in the client side :

```
    this.billsService.getAllModel().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data.text());
        this.image = data.text();
      },  
      (err) => console.log(err),
      () => console.log("Done")
    );
```

html code :

```
<img  src="'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+image"/>
```

So image binary data is successfully  displayed in the console but i can't add it to the html page

**solution :**  thanks to  [Lyubimov Roman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2918518/lyubimov-roman)  , I have solved my issue using blob object and here is my code :

sertvice ts :

```
public getImage() {
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({
      headers, responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob,
    });
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/BillsModel/all', options)
      .map((res: Response) => { return (res); })
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }
```

app component ts

```
this.billsService.getAllModel().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data._body);
        var blob = new Blob([data.blob()], { type: "image/png" });
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (event) => {
          this.URL = reader.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
      },  //changed
      (err) => console.log(err),
      () => console.log("Done")
    );
```

html code :

```
 <img *ngIf="URL" [src]="URL" /> //you need to use *ngIf="URL" , otherwise some browser error could appear
```

and the same back end code

Comment: I guess you should set responseType to blob and then fetch data by reader. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39690808/2918518) to make blob and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650249/2918518) to recieve an image base64 content.

Comment: thanks @LyubimovRoman , it's done with blob , I wish you have post it as answer and not comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set responseType to blob and then fetch data by reader. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39690808/2918518) to make blob and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650249/2918518) to recieve an image base64 content.

Comment: Please include the actual code instead of just links...in case the links become dead in the future

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind a base64 encoded image that you received from the server via angular bindings to the DOM. You need to trust the URL first, otherwise the DomSanitizer will remove it ([see the docs](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustUrl)).

```
url = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('data:image/jpeg;base64,' + image)
```

Then you can use that `url` and bind it: `<img [src]="url">`.